# How to Show Another ViewController by ChartValueSelected from using IOSChart?

Tags: ios, swift, charts, uiviewcontroller, ios-charts

I'm trying to develop a simple active chart. My intention was to have the specific bar selected in the chart to show another view. The main chart was intended to be a dashboard style, so for in-depth discovery or details, user may select the specific bar to learn more [supposedly will show the specific viewcontroller].

```
func chartValueSelected(chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, dataSetIndex: Int, highlight: ChartHighlight) {
    println("\(entry.value) in \(months[entry.xIndex])")

    var storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    var vc: NewViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("newView") as! NewViewController

    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

For each month will have their own views because I am going to put another charts in that specific view. From what I understand, for each month will have the specific function command; so I think of using IF ELSE inside the function but I totally have no clue how to start. I'm also not sure if there are another simpler way to achieve this, as I'm still learning.

I'm following the tutorial for using iOSCharts http://www.appcoda.com/ios-charts-api-tutorial/
and custom show viewcontroller from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0I4HX6NDDak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func chartValueSelected(chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, dataSetIndex: Int, highlight: ChartHighlight) {
    print("\(entry.value) in \(months[entry.xIndex])")

    let strSelectedMonth : String = months[entry.xIndex] as! String

    if strSelectedMonth == "April"
    {
        print(strSelectedMonth)

        // Now push another view controller and display bar chart for April month
    }     
}
```

Dont forget to implement `barChartView.delegate = self` and `ChartViewDelegate`

This solution is best use for showing year, months, days and hours with different view controller and catered data on chart.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! :) Now I'm able to push for more specific views. I'm only working on just simple active charts with predetermined datasets. I'll look forward in using dynamic datasets in the future.

Comment: Good, have a happy coding.

Comment: What will be for swift3? dataSetIndex always 0

Comment: Hi Sofeda, i have just checked with example on https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts , in Swift 3.0 version func chartValueSelected(chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, dataSetIndex: Int, highlight: ChartHighlight)  delegate method is same as earlier.

Comment: @Hasya, I am using same method for push another view controller with selected data. but when I come backt to previous viewcontroller it shows me selected cell. then I need to deselect that then select, how can i avoid this, here i have posted same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43907455/how-to-disable-selection-of-bar-char/

Comment: @VinodJadhav On previous viewcontroller keep debug pointer on viewDidload and viewWillAppear, when you back to previous view controller check debug pointer is getting called or not, if not then i guess something wrong with new to previous view controller navigation. I wish you are using pop or poptoroot view controller.

Comment: @Hasya, viewwillappear method getting called, in that method I have written code for deselect previous selected record "self.regionHorizontalChart.highlightValue(nil)" but it just unhighlight selected bar not actually deselect.

Comment: Can you please check something here https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=chartValueSelected