# How to disable selection of bar char?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I have implemented a bar chart and I would like to move to a more specific on click on that bar chart. for that I am using **"ChartViewDelegate(Chartviewselected)"** it is working fine. but issue is first time when I select bar chart it goes smothly to next screen. but when come back on that screen selected bar shows selected default, when click on that bar again then it gets unselected. **because of that chartview  delegate(chartview selected) method not called**. So I want to disable default selection of bar chart. is there any property to disable selection of bar chart?

Comment: you may want to share some code ?

Answer (score 12):

Use `dataSet.highlightEnabled = false`

Answer (score 0):

When coming back to the screen try calling:

```
  lineview.delegate!.chartValueNothingSelected!(lineview)
```

According to ChartViewBase.swift:

```
// Called when nothing has been selected or an "un-select" has been made.
@objc optional func chartValueNothingSelected(_ chartView: ChartViewBase)
```

Comment: You are right but nothing is done after called chartvaluenothing selected method, I think need to be do some code for unselect programatically in that method.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to removed highlighted Bar while come back from Previous screen put below code in `viewWillApper()` it will remove highlighted Bar.

```
//Manyally Remove Selected Bar 
[self.chartView highlightValues:NULL];
```

Hope this will helps!

Comment: I have already tested this. it just removed highlighted color of bar, not actually deselect that bar.

Comment: in viewwillappear, I also have tried "regionHorizontalChart.highlightValue(NULL, callDelegate: true)". it calls delegate method "chartvaluenothingselected:" but not deselect for delselect that bar I need to click on that bar

Comment: Can you post your `chartValueSelected` method code ?

Comment: there is nothing in "chartvalueselected:" method just added print statement.    func chartValueNothingSelected(_ chartView: ChartViewBase) {
        print("Nothing selected")
        
    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144260/discussion-between-vinod-jadhav-and-codechanger).